# Why template engine doest'n render

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

When I write this code bellow in my login.scala.html, only the words 'foo' are showed, in other words, 'bar' is never showed.

```
<body>
    @{
        <span>bar</span>
        if(true)
        {
            <span>foo</span>
        }
    }

    @{
        <span>bar</span>
        for(i <- numbers)
        {
            <span>bar</span>
            <span>i.toString()</span>
        }
    }
</body>
```

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you used the block statement, it returning the last expression.

For example (try it in REPL):

```
val a: Int = 10 
val b: Int = 20
{
a
b
}
```

Output:

```
res0: Int = 20
```